# How to set child to fill dynamically-sized parent's width

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a design (picture below) where a container's width is dynamically set by the text content it contains. While I can get the text container to fill just fine, I'm struggling to find a suitable solution for the `LinearProgressIndicator` that appears below it. I need the Column sibling to fill to the width of the parent Container yet all of my approaches have come up short.

```
 return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Icon(
                widget.icon,
                size: 48,
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 14),
              Text(
                widget.name,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 32.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          LinearProgressIndicator(
            value: 0.8,
            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 108, 218, 114),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            minHeight: 5,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

I can't seem to wrap the widget with `Expand` or use `double.infinity` width since the parent wrapper has no fixed sized.

I'm curious what approaches I could use to meet the design requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you need here `IntrinsicWidth`. A widget that sizes its child to the child's maximum intrinsic width.

[IntrinsicWidth](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html)

```
Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      color: Colors.orange.shade200,
    ),
    child: IntrinsicWidth(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const Row(
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.home,
                size: 48,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 14),
              Text(
                'Visitors Lodge',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 32.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          LinearProgressIndicator(
            value: 0.8,
            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 108, 218, 114),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            minHeight: 5,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to wrap that LinearProgressIndicator inside a row widget too and put in an expand widget like this:

```
Row(
 children: [
   Expanded(
     child: LinearProgressIndicator(...)
   ),
 ],
),
```